# How to use NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection over a secure connection? (HTTPS)

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm using NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to send web requests to a webserver with a valid ssl certificate. Is there anything special I need to do other than setting the url as https vs. http to get it to use ssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the certificate is valid, there should be no problem.

If it's an untrusted certificate, NSURLConnection has a set of delegate methods to handle authentication challenges:

```
– connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:
– connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
```